# Как сохранить значения для последующего вызова?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть вот такой код:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetParam([FromQuery(Name = "ids")] int[] ids, BidRequestModel bidRequest)
    {
        var result = await _testMsSQL.GetPartnerBl(ids);
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
    }
```

В данном случае необходимо сохранить значения bidRequest для последующего использования в других местах программы, т.е. в этом участке кода ей присваиваются как-то значения, но когда я пытаюсь обратиться к ней в другом месте, то получаю значения null, например здесь значения bidRequest уже равно null и соответсвенно дальше передается тоже null:

```
BidRequestModel bidRequest;
Process(bidRequest, item.Endpoint, protocol);
```

Можно как нибудь сохранить значения bidRequest для последующего использования в программе?

Comment: Вам не должно этого хотеться, по идее. Расскажите, почему вы решили оно вам очень надо? Для чего это? А вообще [есть сессия](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1), к ней можно прицепить какие-то данные.

Comment: Получается, что у меня в контроллере записываются две модели и в последствии они должны быть отправлены, с первой моделью все нормально, но она записывается из БД, вторая все берет из запроса, в нее все номрамльно записывается, но только в контроллере, в отсальном коде она равно null, и мне надо это исправить

Comment: Что такое "остальной код"? Кто его запускает, что он делает?

Comment: Имеется ввиду, код - который работает с этой моделькой (остальной код), он должен забирать  из нее некоторые значения полей

Comment: Яснее не стало, но я не буду больше вас пытать вопросами. Будет неплохо, если вы более предметно опишете логику работы сервера и задачу, которую решаете. Пока видно, какие решения вы приняли, и что хотите сделать, но совершенно непонятно, для чего всё это. [XY-проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567) - прочитайте внимательно и попытайтесь понять, почему я дал вам эту ссылку. После чего отредактируйте вопрос.